# Does "$X \not\to (\omega)^\omega_2$ for every infinite $X$" imply ${\sf AC}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, infinite-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

For any set $X$ and cardinal $\mu \neq \emptyset$, we denote by $[X]^\mu$ the collection of subsets of cardinality $\mu$. If $\kappa, \mu \neq \emptyset$ are cardinals and $f: [X]^\mu\to \kappa$ is a map, we say that $H\subseteq X$ is *homogeneous with respect to $f$* if the restriction $f|_{[H]^\mu}: [H]^\mu \to \kappa$ is constant.

For cardinals $\lambda, \mu, \kappa\neq \emptyset$ and any set $X\neq \emptyset$ we write $$X \to (\lambda)^\mu_\kappa$$ if for every map $f: [X]^\mu\to\kappa$ there is $H\subseteq X$ such that $H$ is homogeneous with respect to $f$ and $|H|=\lambda$.

With the help of the Axiom of Choice ${\sf (AC)}$ one can prove that $X \not\to (\omega)^\omega_2$ for every infinite $X$ (see Theorem 7, p. 5 of [this recommended introduction to infinite combinatorics](https://users.metu.edu.tr/burakk/lecturenotes/village2017lecturenotes.pdf), thank you to Burak for writing it!).

**Question.** Does the statement "$X \not\to (\omega)^\omega_2$ for every infinite set $X$" imply ${\sf (AC)}$?

Comment: Egad, that is bad notation. I find it quite perverse to use the arrow notation both for a structure (a function: the usual notation) and for a property. I quite failed to understand at first that $\not \to$ meant failure of that property.

Comment: As the author of the notes, I tried to use the standard notation (known as the Erdös-Rado arrow notation) instead of inventing a new notation.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I have encountered the notation so many times that I am quite certain that it is standard in that field. For instance Saharon Shelah uses it in many articles. (By the way, I didn't find what "Egad" stands for, I took it to be an abbreviation like "WLG")

Comment: @Burak --> thanks for your wonderful notes which gave me a great entry point to infinite combinatorics!!

Comment: @Burak Okay, my apologies for attributing this to you, and I will remove that attribution. (But I am still of the strong opinion that the notation is terrible!) Dominic: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egad

Comment: @Todd It grows on you.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @ToddTrimble! It seems to me that the use of "Egad" is less common than  denoting a property with $\to$ and $\not\to$ respectively. (Just kidding.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Never!! :-)

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Let me add that the very same notation has a different meaning if you use ordinals instead of cardinals in its slots, which can cause more problems than possible confusion with arrows for functions. Nevertheless, it has been around since (at most) 1953 and is widely used, which means that people probably will keep using it. (This is the earliest use of this notation that I could find: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/jlms/s1-28.4.426)

Comment: @Burak Yeesh! No doubt that would be even worse, since it's now insiders who can get confused. Mathematicians are sometimes just really bad (irreflective) about choosing terminology and notation. I guess the same is true in every sphere of life (time for me to quit this thread, I think).

Comment: Why all this bad publicity? It is useful, and compact. No one who works in the field gets confused.

Comment: Compact it is, but for the life of me I can’t remember which number in the notation denotes which parameter.

Comment: @ToddTrimble After so much input, I think, rather than quitting the thread, you are obliged to propose an alternative notation :P

Comment: If only cardinal and ordinal numbers were under consideration, we could just define $(b)^r_k$ to be the corresponding "Ramsey number" and then we could write $a\ge(b)^r_k$ or $a\lt(b)^r_k$ instead of $a\to(b)^r)_k$ or $a\not\to(b)^r_k$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek As bof points out implicity in his note, the statement $a\to (b)^e_c$ implies all variants where you increase the number on the left side, or decrease anything on the right side.  Also, the exponent $e$ denotes the size  (or order type) of the tuples you are considering, which should be easy to remember.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is no, the statement that for every set $X$ we have $$X\not\to(\omega)^\omega_2$$ does not imply the axiom of choice.

This was shown by Kleinberg and Seiferas in 1973, see

> [MR0340025](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=340025) (49 #4782)
> Kleinberg, E. M.; Seiferas, J. I.
> Infinite exponent partition relations and well-ordered choice.
> J. Symbolic Logic 38 (1973), 299–308.
> https://doi.org/10.2307/2272066

For $\kappa$ a (well-ordered) infinite cardinal, $\kappa$-well-ordered choice, $\mathsf{AC}_\kappa$, is the statement that every $\kappa$-sequence of nonempty sets admits a choice function.

The axiom of well-ordered choice $\mathsf{WOC}$ is the statement that $\mathsf{AC}_\kappa$ holds for all infinite well-ordered $\kappa$.

This statement is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice: it does not imply that $\mathbb R$ is well-orderable, and even if we add this assumption, the result is still weaker than choice. See for instance theorem 5.1 in

> [MR1351415](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1351415) (96h:03087)
> Higasikawa, Masasi
> Partition principles and infinite sums of cardinal numbers.
> Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 36 (1995), no. 3, 425–434. https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1040149358

However, as shown in the paper by Kleinberg and Seiferas, $\mathsf{WOC}$ plus the existence of a well-ordering of $[\omega]^\omega$ rules out all infinite exponent partition relations. It is still open (as far as I know) whether $\mathsf{WOC}$ suffices for this result. What Kleinberg and Seiferas show is that, under $\mathsf{WOC}$, either all infinite exponent partition relations fail, or else $\omega\to(\omega)^\omega_2$. (And the latter fails if $[\omega]^\omega$ is well-orderable.)

Comment: So, really it's just WOC + $\omega\nrightarrow(\omega)^\omega_2$, which is a consequence of WOC + well-orderable continuum. And the question remains whether or not the partition relation just follows from WOC, and can therefore be eliminated as an explicit assumption? If $\omega\to(\omega)^\omega_2$ has some LC strength to it, that means that we can arrange all kind of models where the continuum is not well-orderable, but the partition relation fails and WOC holds, just by taking symmetric extensions over some LC-challenged model.

Comment: Yes, that's the situation at the moment.  And sure, if we knew that the Mathias relation gives you an inaccessible, we would be done. The alternative is to force $\mathsf{WOC}$ over, say, a Solovay model, while preserving the relation.

Comment: Do we even know that WOC is forceable over Solovay models (without forcing full AC, that is)?